# Displaying a number on the current user's posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This sounds like an easy question but for some reason I am lost.

In my user's profile page, I'm showing all of their posts. If they have 3 posts, I want to show something like this.

```
1. Post one title
2. Post two title
3. Post three title
```

So it shows the number to the left of the post. This cannot be the post's ID though. Do anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, check out `Enumerable#each_with_index`. So you can do something like:

```
@posts.each_with_index do |post, index|
  puts "#{index} #{post}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks @jklina that works and I will accept it when it allows me to. How can I start the numbering from 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Just use `"#{index + 1} #{post}"`.

Comment: There's actually a method for that too. `Enumerable#with_index` http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index . This let's you provide an offset.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you can rely on the HTML for the enumeration. Just use an ordered list.

```
<ol>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
   <li><%= post.title %></li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

For anything more elaborate than this, [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) will be your best choice.